# How to set the database connection for Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first

I created a database with Entity Framework Code First.

I set the database connection in app.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Automation;User ID=sa;Password=pass"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

when run application, database created in server "." and "/SqlExpress".

and when i insert data in it, it insert in "/sqlexpress" and don't insert in server "."

Answer (score 0):

create two instances of connectionstring.

e.g

DataContext context = new DataContext(connectionstring 1);

DataContext context2 = new DataContext(connectionstring 2);